# How to add images to a word (docx) template in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pandoc

I have a docx template with header and footer and some text in it. Now I want to add some images with a specified max size to the document.

If I try and do it with pandoc-ruby gem and generate a html string and convert it to a word document, then I don't get an option to add header and footer to the generated doc using pandoc.

Comment: you can d it using caracal gem

Comment: How do you save a caracal doc? When I run Caracal::Document.save "#{Rails.root}/tmp/example.docx", it gives me an error -> NameError: uninitialized constant Zip::OutputStream, even though I have zip installed.

Comment: something like `PandocRuby.convert('<h1>my html</h1>', :s, {:f => :html, :to => :docx}, 'reference-docx=myfile.docx')` ?

Comment: I tried using the above method of passing a reference_doc and it is working but somehow the style information is not getting picked up. For eg. when I pass something like this as the html part :-                                                <br><P style="text-align: center"><u><b><span style="font-size: 16px">Employment 1 MAILS/EXTRACTS</span></b></u></P></br>              It just prints "Employment 1 MAILS/EXTRACTS" w/o any style information like the font size, the text alignment and not even the underline part. Is there a way through which I can pass the style information as well?

Comment: @ParthNagori no, pandoc doesn't include style information, only the [semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_HTML)

Answer (score 3):

After trying multiple approaches, I ended up writing a gem [Omnidocx](https://rubygems.org/gems/omnidocx) to get this done.

You can find the source code of the gem [here](https://github.com/parthnagori/omnidocx).

Please find an example to add images to the doc using the gem Omnidocx below this line.

```
    images_to_write = [ {
                      :path => "tmp/image1.jpg",     #URL || local path
                      :height => 500,
                      :width => 500,
                      :hdpi => 115,       #optional
                      :vdpi => 115        #optional
                      },
                      :path => "www.xyz.com/abc.jpeg",    #URL || local path
                      :height => 800,
                      :width => 500,
                      :hdpi => 115,       #optional
                      :vdpi => 115        #optional
                      }
                    ]   
    Omnidocx::Docx.write_images_to_doc(images_to_write=[], input_document_path, output_document_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

May use the gem htmltoword'
https://github.com/karnov/htmltoword
I did these actions.
In Mime_types I set

```
Mime::Type.register "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", :docx
```

In Routes I set

```
get "create_docx" => "Some_controllers#create_docx", format: 'docx'
```

I created action 'create_docx' in 'Some_controller', then I passed HTML-object for example

```
@thumb = Nokogiri::HTML::Document.parse(@fips_tz.doc).css('img')[1]
```

I got docx with img frpm URI '/Some_controller/create_docx'
Do not set format in action, we get error 'Unrecognized unit of measure:' otherwise.
https://github.com/karnov/htmltoword/issues/66